# Controlling number of threads in Mule

Tags: threadpool, mule

I'm using Mule 3.3.1 Community Edition.

I have a flow that accepts HTTP requests.  This runs successfully.

```
<flow name="TestFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" 
        host="localhost" port="8088" path="test" doc:name="HTTP" mimeType="text/plain"
        encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <logger level="INFO" category="hello" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

The service needs to be single-threaded so that messages are handled strictly in the order in which they are received.  My thought was to set maxThreadsActive=1 and maxBufferSize=100 to get my desired behavior.  However, I can't get any control over threads to work.

At this point I'm just trying to get a thread profile working, regardless of the number of threads. I added a threading-profile exactly out of the current version of the Manning book *Mule in Action*, but Mule rejects it as "Invalid content" and won't run.

```
<flow name="TestFlow">
    <threading-profile maxBufferSize="100" maxThreadsActive="20" maxThreadsIdle="10"
        threadTTL="60000" poolExhaustedAction="RUN" />

    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" 
        host="localhost" port="8088" path="test" doc:name="HTTP" mimeType="text/plain"
        encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <logger level="INFO" category="hello" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

I commented that out and moved up to a configuration block.

```
<configuration>
    <default-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="20" maxBufferSize="100" 
         poolExhaustedAction="RUN" />
</configuration>

<flow name="TestFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" 
        host="localhost" port="8088" path="test" doc:name="HTTP" mimeType="text/plain"
        encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <logger level="INFO" category="hello" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Mule accepts this, but the service no longer returns; the client simply hangs waiting for a response.

How do I configure my flow so that I can control thread pool size and, once that's done, so that only one thread is available in the pool?

Comment: In poking around this some more, it appears that setting maxBufferSize is causing the failure in the second attempt to configure.  If I remove that attribute, the service returns.  However, since the default is zero, I can't live with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the `receiver-threading-profile` of the HTTP connector:

```
<http:connector name="httpConnector">
  <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1" />
</http:connector>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  As a side note, can you tell me why the use of the maxBufferSize attribute on the default-threading-profile causes the service to hang up?

Comment: Sorry, I've tried different configurations with `maxBufferSize="10"` but can't cause the service to hang up. Please open a new question and post the configuration that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: what happened with this??? does anyone knows what's the proper value for maxBufferSize and maxThreadsActive? Thanks

Comment: msqar: it would depend on your configuration, requirements and resources. There is not a simple 'it is X' answer.